# Is it possible to store boxed arrays as memory mapped files in J?

Tags: j

I have data that works well in j files and key files but for possible performance reasons memory mapped files make more sense. At one time J did have MMF's for boxed arrays but I think it was discontinued. I think JD has this feature now.

What are the best options for memory mapping boxed arrays in J?

Arrays with a min to max column count ratio of 1/100 seem best suited for boxed arrays. I recall reading in the JD docs that the recommendation to consider switching to boxed arrays, using JD, was 1/50.

Comment: Without knowing more about your needs, data format, and access patterns, it's difficult to give a conclusive answer.  But if you just need a list of variable-length lists, all the same data type, then perhaps consider one mapped file for the data, and another which is a list of start/end offsets.  This permits random access, efficient extraction of a selection of elements, and efficient appending.  And it's more space-efficient for the offsets array than a list of offset+length, since you can share the end offset of one record with the start offset of the next.